# Weird lines while hovering over review progress bar

Tags: bug, review-queues, badge-progress

When you hover over the review progress bar (the one in between `194` and `stats` from pic below), a badge-progress-menu appears, that has some weird lines to the left of the menu that should not appear

[image]

Attempted in Firefox and Chrome but reproduced only in Chrome *(Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)) on Windows*

Comment: I've seen this on random pop-ups/hover boxes such as the box that appears when you hover over a tag...the past few days

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 67 for Mac.

Comment: Still, in my experience this kind of issues are artifacts caused by very specific combinations of browser, platform and graphic card. Very hard to reproduce or "fix", since the problem is too localized.

Comment: Interestingly the lines are horizontal on my desktop PC but vertical on my laptop. Chrome Version 68.0.3440.33 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on Windows

Comment: Same here, but vertical? https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH7YR.png

Comment: same with vertical here :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375958/display-glitch-when-hovering-over-review-queues-badge-progression-bar?noredirect=1#comment642386_375958 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRjhj.png (Chrome 69, dual screens, resolutions 1920 * 1200 and 1920 * 1080, bug on both)

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Vertical lines seen on badge progress page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313837/289905).